# Quick Acceleration Vector Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was studying for a test and found the following prompt:

"A student programs a robot to move across a flat surface over the time interval $0≤t≤20$  seconds. The position of the robot at time $t$ seconds is given by the parametric equations  $x(t)=3t+\sin(t)$ and $y(t)=3\cos(t−\sin(t))$, where  $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are measured in meters. The derivatives of these functions are given by $x′(t)=3+\cos(t)$ and $y(t)=−3\sin(t-\sin(t))⋅(1−\cos(t))$. Find the acceleration vector of the robot at the time when the robot is at the point with $x$-coordinate $50$."

I guess I'm a bit confused about what the actual equation for the vector would look like here. I understand that an acceleration vector can be found by taking the derivative of a velocity vector, but I'm confused about how either would be found in this context. I'm also confused about what I would have to plug into these equations once they have been found. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you wrote it correctly?  When the $x$-coordinate is $50$ then $t$ solves $3t + \sin(t) = 50$, which has to be approximated numerically.

Comment: So, I'm coming up with a $t$ value of $16.9$. Would that then be plugged into the equation for $y(t)$? Or would I have to plug it into one of its derivatives?

Comment: Take the derivative of each velocity equation to get acceleration, and plug your $t$ value into those.